# PC will not power on with normal power supply

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power

My ASUS M2N-SLI motherboard would not turn back on after running fine for five years. I connected a new (still in the box) 430 W power supply - ATX 2.1 - the system powers on. The power supply doesn't have enough correct connections to use in this machine.

I shut down my other PC and took the 1000 W power supply from it and connected to the ASUS motherboard - same issue - light is on, fans bump over then stop. I disconnected everything from the motherboard and tested - same result. I tried again with the 430 W power supply - it turns on. I then put the original power supply from the ASUS M2N into my other machine to verify bad and the light was on, fans bumped over, and NO boot or beeps.

Then I put the 1000 W PS back into my other machine and now it is doing the same - light is on, fans bump over, no boot and no beeps. I disconnected everything from the motherboard - same result. I ordered a new power supply, but now I'm concerned that the bad power supply may have damaged the motherboard and the motherboard may damage the power supply so that plugging the new power supply into either will kill it too.

Why does the system boot with an older-version power supply, but not newer? Could a motherboard kill a power supply? I know the power supply could kill the board, and that's why I already ordered a new power supply.

Any ideas I might not have thought of? It's bad timing to have to replace two USD$1500 builds, so I would appreciate helpful suggestions.

Comment: Is your motherboard touching the chassis or are there spacers in between?

Comment: "The power supply doesn't have enough correct connections to use in this machine." So what did you leave out? That might be the troublemaker.

Comment: MB is not touching chassis - has worked for 5 years. I didn't leave anything out - I only used the other power supply to test the MB and RAM; video complained because no power. No integrated video to use but that is irrelevant as it won't even power on with/without video. Anything I "left out" would just beep an error - the 430W PS doesn't provide power to video but does everything else. System powers up with 430 even with ALL devices plugged in, just no video to see if Windows or HDD are working.

Comment: The question I'm asking is why it won't power up with a proper power supply and could it have damaged the PS from my other working system - which is now also NOT working and having the same problem, so two PS down now.

Answer (score 0):

This motherboard won't work without both the main power connector and the 4-pin auxiliary connector that is seen on the right, near the top;  what you describe is a typical symptom of not having the 4-pin connector inserted, or having it in an incorrect orientation.

[image]